# single SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

im working on a project where a chat feature has already been implemented.. the database structure is as follows:

## Table Chats

```
id              // auto-incrementing message id
created_by_id   // user id of person who wrote this message
reply_to_id     // id of FIRST message this message is in reply to (0 if new message)
creation_date   // creation timestamp
text            // message content
```

## Table Tags

```
chat_id         // message id this row corresponds to
user_id         // user id of person who is an audience of this message
is_unread       // has the user read this message?
```

## Table Users

```
id              // auto-incrementing id
name            // name of user
```

## Sample Data

```
CHATS
1, {ME},  0, {DATE}, 'This is a new message'
2, {HIM}, 1, {DATE}, 'This is a reply to the above message'
3, {HER}, 1, {DATE}, 'So is this one'
4, {HER}, 1, {DATE}, 'Another reply from HER'
5, {YOU}, 0, {DATE}, 'This is a different conversation'

TAGS
1, {ME},  0  // ME, HIM and HER as audience, so 3 rows here
1, {HIM}, 0
1, {HER}, 0
2, {HIM}, 0  // ME, HIM and HER here as well
2, {ME},  1
2, {HER}, 0
3, {HER}, 0  // ME, HIM and HER here as well
3, {ME},  1
3, {HIM}, 1
4, {YOU}, 0  // YOU and HER as audience, so 2 rows here (ME and HIM should not see this)
4, {HER}, 1
```

this works fine for our purposes.. besides, the tables are used in a legacy app as well and hence the structure cant be changed..

now i have to display these messages inside two views.. a conversations view.. and a messages inside a single conversation view..

for the conversations view, i need to design an SQL query such that each row contains the following (without making N sub-queries):

- initial chat id (`id` where `reply_to_id = 0`)
- recent most chat id (the greatest `reply_to_id` in a conversation)
- recent most chat message
- a list of recipients of the message (`tag.chat_id = chat.id`)

can someone help me or guide me towards a solution? specifically, i need guidance for the following:

- i can find the conversation id for a message by `IF (reply_to_id = 0, id, reply_to_id)`.. i can group by it as well to return a single conversation row.. however i can not retrieve the latest row in this group..
- equally important, i need to find all recipients of this message.. as an array or even a comma-separated string.. but i have no idea how to..
- i need to implement a paging solution later on.. im pretty sure this will also dictate how the query is written..

thanks..

awesim

---

## EDIT

this is the query im working with right now.. it works fine, except that i cannot find all the recipients of a conversation without a separate query..

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        IF (c.reply_to_id = 0, c.id, c.reply_to_id) as conv_id,
        c.*,
        t.*
    FROM chats AS c
    INNER JOIN tags AS t
        ON t.chat_id = c.id OR t.chat_id = c.reply_to_id
    WHERE
        t.user_id = {ME}
    ORDER BY
        creation_date DESC
) AS data
GROUP BY conv_id
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

how can i also find the list of recipients within this query?

Comment: after the inner join tags, you need to join users on t.user_id = u.id to get a record for each user.. not sure how to get the last message in a group in a single query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your query does provide a single row per conversion, then you can use the GROUP_CONCAT function to get the recipients of the final chat in the series:

```
SELECT {other fields}, GROUP_CONCAT(tags.user_id) AS list_of_recipients
FROM
{your query}
) AS conversation
INNER JOIN tags on conversation.conv_id=tags.chat_id
GROUP BY conversation.conv_id
```

However, I don't really see how to get all of the other fields nicely (though it may be possible).

Here's an alternative I wrote but haven't tested. The basic idea is that I want to find the first and last chat_id in the conversation, and drop all of the ones in the middle. So I create pair1 that will be used to identify the first pair in the chain, and pair2 that will be used to identify the last pair in the chair. Then I join the second chat in the first pair to the first chat in the second pair. Next I select out from this new pair3 the rows where the first chat_id is indeed the initial chat, and the last chat_id is indeed the last. I then pick up the body text of the chat through a join, and all of the recipients through another join. Grouping on the first and last chat ids lets me concatenate all the recipients into a single value. I use FIRST() to inexpensively get the text. If you need to join the list of recipients to the users table you might want to do that rather than the GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT. Or perhaps if you want a list of names you could join to users table and then do GROUP_CONCAT on their names.

HTH

```
    SELECT initial_chat_id, most_recent_chat_id, 
FIRST(most_recent_chat.text), 
GROUP_CONCAT(tags.user_id) AS list_of_recipients_most_recent_chat
    FROM
    (
    SELECT prev1_id as initial_chat_id, max(IF(next2_id IS NULL,prev1_id,next2_id)) as most_recent_chat_id
    FROM
    (
    (SELECT prev_chat.id AS prev1_id, prev_chat.reply_to_id as prev1_reply_id, 
    next_chat.id AS next1_id
    FROM chats prev_chat LEFT JOIN
    chats next_chat on prev_chat.id=next_chat.reply_to_id) AS pair1
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT prev_chat.id AS prev2_id, prev_chat.reply_to_id as prev2_reply_id, 
    next_chat.id AS next2_id
    FROM chats prev_chat LEFT JOIN
    chats next_chat on prev_chat.id=next_chat.reply_to_id) AS pair2
    ON pair1.next_id=pair2.prev_id) as pair3 
    WHERE
    prev1_reply_id IS NULL AND next2_id IS NULL) AS conversation
    INNER JOIN tags ON conversation.most_recent_chat_id=tags.chat_id 
    INNER JOIN chats most_recent_chat ON conversation.most_recent_chat_id=most_recent_chat.id
    GROUP BY initial_chat_id, most_recent_chat_id, tags.chat_id;
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.. im trying to understand it and to get it to work (there was an error in my problem statement, see edit).. you just taught me a couple of new things here.. :)